# "File > External Data > Report missing files" reports dozens of "missing" .blend files?

Tags: blend-files

I have a second Windows PC that I dedicate to rendering some of my Blender projects, so needless to say, managing dependencies (external textures, etc.) is an ongoing process. Here's something I'm trying to figure out:

**File > External Data > Report missing files** reports dozens, sometimes hundreds, of "missing" blend, files. All of these missing blend files are from other projects, and have nothing to do with the current blend file.

This isn't a showstopper, but it does clutter the reporting process, continually leads me to ask: Why?

Blender 3.0, Windows 11

Comment: In some way your blend file is referencing these external files.   If you use the Outliner, "Blender File" mode (drop down to the right of the Outliner symbol in the header).  You can try to search for a fragment of the file name reported, and see what is referring to such an external fil (Image node, etc). you can find this node, right-click and Delete.

Comment: Hi :). I guess it's to save you from checking each linked .blend individually if you have tens of linked assets

Comment: @james_t Oh my lord, why didn't i think of the search function last week! :)) So simple. Thanks.

Comment: @james_t Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, none of the referenced files show up by searching the Outliner.